# Publish ASP.net Core Web App with Databases from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: database, web-applications, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, publish

I've created an asp.net core web app which has a database generated by the framework for user registration and login, and another database generated from a Model using migrations. I want to publish this website to my university server that was set up my a support guy for me.
Using the Publish by web deploy features in Visual Studio I have been able to publish the site to the server and view it via the designated URL. However, the databases don't work yet.
When developing the web app on my PC, visual studio used localdb connection strings to generate and connect to the databases. The problem is, I don't know what I need to change, or what settings I need to use so that this works on the live site. In particular I think I need the correct setting in the Databases and Entity Framework Migrations sections of the VC publish wizard:

[image]

The image shows the connection strings used when running the app locally on my PC. I need to know what to put in those 4 cells when publishing to the server. All of the tutorials I've found are based around VS2012 which looks quite different.
The main problem that I currently have after deployment is this. When run locally for the first time, when I go to register a new user, the webpage offers to add the migrations because the database does not yet exist. On the deployed website this does not happen. I just get:

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HLD51G3G3C07:00000002 
Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred. 
Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.
```

Can anybody help?